# Apache Tomee session Management with gemFire Integration

Tags: session, gemfire, session-management, apache-tomee

I am trying to do session management using tomcat modules in gemFire. Reference link we used is [https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/95/geode/tools_modules/http_session_mgmt/tomcat_installing_the_module.html].
      Application server that we are using is tomee 7.0.5. After making the changes mentioned in the link.  When i tried to make the server up, we were getting an error "getContainer() method not found in class DeltaSessionManager".There is a module geode-modules-9.5.1.jar provided by gemFire(gfsh Client) which helps for session management. Inside that there is a class DeltaSessionManager which extends another class org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase . But the ManagerBase class in catalina.jar inside tomee 7.0.5 doesn't have this method. But when we downloaded tomcat catalina jar separately we were able to see this method. Is there any difference in the approach for tomee.
Any help would be appreciable

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the tomee source code, I suspect tomee 7.0.5 is actually embedding Tomcat 8. In that case, you need to use Tomcat8DeltaSessionManager, which supports Tomcat 8 and above.